# Proove $3^n$ divides $a(n)$ for all integers $n\ge 1$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

**Q.** Define a sequence of integers $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$...

$a_1=3$, $a_2=18$ and $a_n=6a_{n-1} - 9a_{n-2}$ for each integer $n\ge 3$.

Prove by strong induction that $3^n$ divides $a_n$ for all integers $n\ge 1$.

**A.** How I approached the question: 
Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $P(n) = \dfrac{a_n}{3^n}$ for integers $n\ge 1$.

Base step for n=1

P(1) = a<sub>1</sub>/3^1

a<sub>1</sub> is 3 so P(1) = 3/3 = 1, So P(1) ist true

Inductive step: Assume n=k is true for some integer k>=1 where a<sub>k</sub> = 6a<sub>k-1</sub> - 9a<sub>k-2</sub> and P(k)=a<sub>k</sub>/3^k

Show P(k+1) = a<sub>k+1</sub>/3^(k+1)

Since a<sub>k</sub> = 6a<sub>k-1</sub> - 9a<sub>k-2</sub> we know a<sub>k+1</sub> = 6a<sub>k</sub> - 9a<sub>k-1</sub>

So a<sub>k+1</sub> = 3(2a<sub>k</sub> - 3a<sub>k-1</sub>)

We can take (2a<sub>k</sub> - 3a<sub>k-1</sub>) as an integer i, and we get a<sub>k+1</sub> = 3i.

From this we can see that 3i is always divisble by 3 regardless the value if the value of i. Hence we have proven by the Principal of Strong Mathamatical induction that P(n) is true for integers n>=3.

I am not really good at strong induction and I do not think that the steps for my strong induction proof is correct over here. Can any one confirm if this was the correct way to solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First you make it a bit more complicated than it is necessary. To be honest, I don't get exactly your notations. But it's sure you would have to verify the case $n=2$ too.

Comment: The way I would prove it: the first cases are true: 3 is divisible by three, and also 18 is divisible by $3^2$. Now suppose that for every $k$ not greater than $n$ holds that $3^k$ is a divisor of $a_k$, specially we can write $a_{n-1}=3^{n-1}k$ and $a_{n}=3^{n}m$ where $k$ and $m$ are integers. By the definition $a_{n+1}=6 \cdot 3^{n}m + 9 \cdot 3^{n-1}k=3^{n+1}( 2m+k) $ which shows what we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_1=3$, $a_2=18$, $a_n = 6a_{n-1}-9a_{n-2}$.

First, $3|3=a_1$, $3^2=9|18=a_2$, so we know the statement is true for $n=1,2$. So we assume that it is true for all $n$ up to $k$, and proceed to prove it for $n=k+1$.

In other words, we assume that for every $n\leq k$, $a_n = 6a_{n-1}-9a_{n-2}$ is divisible by $3^n$, and proceed to show that $a_{k+1} = 6a_k - 9a_{k-1}$ is divisible by $3^{k+1}$.

$a_{k+1} = 6a_k-9a_{k-1}$

Since by our induction hypothesis, $a_k$ is divisible by $3^k$, we have $a_k = 3^k r$, and since $a_{k-1}$ is divisible by $3^{k-1}$, we have $a_{k-1}=3^{k-1}s$ for $r$, $s$ integers. We conclude

$a_{k+1} = 6\cdot 3^k r - 3^2\cdot 3^{k-1}s = 3^{k+1}(2r-s)$

which is what we wanted.